# How to make recursive function to work in procedural order in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to make a calendar array in Node.js.
this is my `main.mts`:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

function nextDay(d: string) {
    const e = dayjs(d, 'MMM D, YYYY (ddd)');
    const f = dayjs(e).add(1, 'day');
    return dayjs(f).format('MMM D, YYYY (ddd)');
}

export class CalendarEdit {
    private cal: string[] = [];
    constructor(d: string) {
        this.cal.push(d);
        this.init(365).catch(err => { throw err; });
    }

    public addDate() {
        const d = this.cal[this.cal.length - 1];
        const e = nextDay(d);
        this.cal.push(e);
    }

    private init(j: number) {
        this.addDate();
        if (j > 1)
            this.init(j - 1);
    }

    public printCal() {
        console.log(this.cal);
    }
}
```

but result says every element in `cal` array is same, which has to be last day of calendar.
I know that JavaScript is basically non-blocking language, but I cannot find a way.
I tried callbacks and promises, and `async`, `await` pairs.
but none of them worked.

I googled it but I cannot find a solution does work on my case.
anyone knows the answer?

**EDIT**: I call `CalendarEdit` in my `index.mts` like this:

```
import { CalendarEdit } from './main';

let cal = new CalendarEdit('Jun 1, 2022 (Wed)');
cal.printCal();
```

Comment: I don't get why `init` is marked as `async` and is `await`ing stuff. There's nothing asynchronous in your code. Write simple synchronous code.

Comment: @Bergi I already tried synchronous one, but that also did not work.

Comment: Please show us that attempt. Where do you output `cal`? How do you create a `CalendarEdit`, how do you use it?

Comment: @Bergi I added it on my post. note that I am using Node.js 16.15.0 LTS on M1 Mac.

Comment: It seems like my Mac is going strange... I tested same code on Windows, just deleting ```async``` and ```await```, and it works!

Comment: nah, in Windows also doesn't work, again

Comment: Have you done some debugging? Does `nextDay` return the expected values each time? I'll guess that it's timezone- and time-of-day dependent.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I tested `nextDay()` and it works perfectly.

Comment: So in which step does it stop working?

Comment: @Bergi I think I just found a bug. `init` or `addDate` seems to overwriting already pushed dates. I'm working with `setTimeout()` now...

Comment: No, please don't! Make your entire script synchronous, there should be nothing asynchronous and no timeouts in there. Also, `.push()` does *not* overwrite anything

Comment: @Bergi yes, I made entire script synchronous. `setTimeout()` was just for debugging. I finally found solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I edited my `addDate()` to this and it solved error:

```
public addDate() {
    const d = nextDay(this.cal[this.cal.length - 1]);
    this.cal.push(d);
}
```